# How to display centered multiline text shortened with ellipsis?

Tags: css, overflow, word-wrap

I have a table (not `<table>` but made of `<div>`s) showing user-defined text. The text can be displayed in up to three text rows (inside a single table cell) and usually fits nicely. It can look like

```
Sed ut perspiciatis         Nor again is there anyone who loves or 
  unde omnis iste    X120    pursues or desires to obtain pain of   
   natus error                   itself, because it is pain
```

However, sometimes the text doesn't fit and then it must be shortened. I can clip it using `overflow: hidden`, but I'd like to display ellipsis when this happens. However, `text-overflow: ellipsis` doesn't work and according to [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/) it's not expected to:

> Note that `text-overflow` only occurs when the container's `overflow` property has the value `hidden`, `scroll` or `auto` and `white-space: nowrap`.

I obviously can't use `white-space: nowrap` as I don't want a single line text.

*How can I show the ellipsis, when the text overflows, while otherwise keeping the behavior (wrapping in up to three lines and vertical and horizontal centering)?*

**This question is not a real duplicate as using `display: -webkit-box` doesn't allow me to center the text both horizontally and vertically.**

Comment: Can you please share a little working example please ?

Comment: @johannchopin *How could I when nothing I tried worked?* I used a `div` with something like `overflow: hidden; display: table-cell; width: ...; height: ...; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;`, but couldn't get the ellipsis.